# Cucumber Java - ExtentReports - IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, runner

Hi community: I'm facing some issues with trying to implement Extent Reports in Cucumber.

I'm receiving this issue after execution:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at cucumber.runtime.io.ResourceLoaderClassFinder.loadClass(ResourceLoaderClassFinder.java:38)
    at cucumber.runtime.io.ResourceLoaderClassFinder.getDescendants(ResourceLoaderClassFinder.java:26)
    at cucumber.runtime.Reflections.instantiateSubclasses(Reflections.java:28)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.loadBackends(Runtime.java:99)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:66)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)


Process finished with exit code 255
```

This is my POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>rodriguitos</groupId>
    <artifactId>zero</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>repo.bodar.com</id>
        <url>http://repo.bodar.com</url>
    </repository>
    </repositories>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.version>3.7.0</maven.compiler.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <cucumber.version>3.0.2</cucumber.version>
        <selenium.version>3.12.0</selenium.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
       <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java8 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-picocontainer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>28.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- REPORTING -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.totallylazy</groupId>
            <artifactId>totallylazy</artifactId>
            <version>1.86</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/cucumber-reporting -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>4.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vimalselvam/cucumber-extentsreport -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber3-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>src/test/java/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*ReportsRunner.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                <version>4.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execution</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectName>zero</projectName>
                            <outputDirectory>/target/reports/cucumber-reports</outputDirectory>
                            <cucumberOutput>/target/reports/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput>
                            <skippedFails>true</skippedFails>
                            <enableFlashCharts>false</enableFlashCharts>
                            <buildNumber>42</buildNumber>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I don't know if it was necessary, but this is my runner:

```
import com.cucumber.listener.ExtentProperties;
import com.cucumber.listener.Reporter;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import managers.FileReadManager;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"src/test/java/features"},
        glue = {"stepdefs"},
        plugin = {"pretty", "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:target/extent-reports/report.html"}
)

public class ExtentsReportsRunner {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new Date());
        ExtentProperties extentProperties = ExtentProperties.INSTANCE;
        extentProperties.setReportPath("extent-reports/"+timeStamp.replace(":","_").replace(".","_")+".html");
    }


    @AfterClass
    public static void createExtentReport() {
        Reporter.loadXMLConfig(new File(FileReadManager.FileReaderManager.getInstance().getConfigReader().getReportConfigPath()));
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("user", System.getProperty("user.name"));
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("os", "Mac OSX");
        Reporter.setTestRunnerOutput("Creating Extent Reports...");
    }
}
```

I know that Extent Reports work with info.cukes instead of io.cucumber and I know this is the right version of java cucumber:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

Can anybody help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use the same version of all cucumber-jvm jars. Now you are using v3.0.2 for most jars (io.cucumber:cucumber-xxx) but v1.2.5 for cucumber-java (info.cukes:cucumber-java). If Extent Reports only work with cucumber-jvm v1.2.5, then you must use v1.2.5 for all cucumber-jvm jars (info.cukes:cucumber-xxx), and also use a info.cukes version of cucumber-jvm-deps.

Comment: What's the difference if I use io.cucumber instead of info.cukes?

Comment: Thanks: That was the solution: Have all the dependencies in version 1.2.5 of info.cukes.

Comment: The group is changed for cucumber-jvm after v1.2.5, so cucumber-jvm v2 and later have the group id io.cucumber, and cucumber-jvm v1.2.5 and earlier have the group id info.cukes.

Comment: Bjorn: If I wanted to work with io.cucumber which number of version should I use for?

Comment: Search for Cucumber-JVM on Maven Central (https://search.maven.org/search?q=Cucumber-JVM). Today Mars 1 of 2020 the latest Cucumber-JVM version is 5.4.1.